# push notification to specific user in PHP

Tags: android, push-notification, laravel-7, onesignal

I want to send push notification to a specific user using PHP.
Able to send push notification to all users via OneSignal but unable to send it to specific user.
**Have created android app using web view**
As per documentation it requires device id ,but have no idea to fetch via php.

1> Is there any requirement to add another library for push notification for my app.
2> How to fetch Device ID via php required for push notification
3> How to do push notification for specific users

Framework: Laravel
App : Android

```
    <?PHP
function sendMessage() {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => 'English Message'
    );
    $hashes_array = array();
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "like-button",
        "text" => "Like",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));
    array_push($hashes_array, array(
        "id" => "like-button-2",
        "text" => "Like2",
        "icon" => "http://i.imgur.com/N8SN8ZS.png",
        "url" => "https://yoursite.com"
    ));
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "my_app_id",
        'included_segments' => array(
            'Subscribed Users'
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        'contents' => $content,
        'web_buttons' => $hashes_array
    );
    
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic Auth Key'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $response;
}

$response = sendMessage();
$return["allresponses"] = $response;
$return = json_encode($return);

$data = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($data);
$id = $data['id'];
print_r($id);

print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
print($return);
print("\n");
?>
```

[Send push notification to specific user using Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33619335/send-push-notification-to-specific-user-using-parse)

[Send Notification to specific user using onesignal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42709827/send-notification-to-specific-user-using-onesignal)

**Onesignal documentation**
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification

Answer (score 0):

According to their API [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/segmentation#filter-types) ...one could send to different segments: `EMAIL`, [`USER TAG`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-tags), `TEST USERS`. Their sample code hints for [`filters`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#example-code---create-notification) (the only option while not storing the tokens):

```
$fields = [
    ...
    'filters' => [
        ["field" => "external_user_id" "relation" => "=", "value" => $user->id]
    ]
];
```

---

Their [FAQ](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications#faq) also features your question:

> How do I send a notification to a single user?

In PHP this shouldn't be any different, while it clearly hints for "your database" (Eloquent `Model`), which should be able to translate `int $user_id` to `string` or `string[]` `$registration_id` aka device registration token. This means that your `MessagingService` implementation/s would need to tell Laravel API about their current token - else these would  be unknown when sending.

I'd rather give a Java answer to a PHP question:

Use method [`.setExternalUserId()`](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#sdk-setexternaluserid-method) to set the Laravel `int $user_id`, once it is known to the mobile client. When using `external_user_id` as filter criteria, one should also set up [identity verification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/identity-verification).

---

Generally one has the option to store tokens and then look them up again
... or to use `.setExternalUserId()`, which then can be used as filter criteria.

The mobile client either has to pass it's token - or it's `int $user_id` / `string $email`.